# is there a way to to so : select T1.id from T1 where T1.col first 5 character = string1

Tags: sql

I have one table T1 and a string string1.
what i want :

```
select T1.id from T1 where  T1.col first 5 character = string1.
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: which rdms are you using, each has a different approach

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please work out which database system you're using. Then perhaps also spend a few minutes looking at that database system's documentation around string manipulation functions. It's not like these details are hidden in books or behind paywalls these days.

Comment: look in your dbms's docs for substring/substr examples. Or maybe mid/left if you are unfortunate enough to using MS Access :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
select T1.id from T1 where left(T1.col,5)  = string1
```

Here's an example if you had a string there

```
select T1.id from T1 where left(T1.col,5)  = 'pizza'
```

And here is how you do it if you want only the first 5 of the string as well:

```
select T1.id from T1 where left(T1.col,5)  = left(string1,5)
```

or with a value

```
select T1.id from T1 where left(T1.col,5)  = left('Longer text value',5)
```

I also saw that you have a . after String1... When this happens it means the table name is String1, then after the . would be your column that has your value. But you cannot have a String1. because it would error out due to no column specified.